# Scaling an 3D object gives weird results

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d

I have two objects in a scene - a cube and a plane. I want the plane to be much larger as it will represent the ground.

When I load my model file, both of my objects are in the same width and depth.

This is my onDrawFrame event:

```
gl.glClear( GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

gl.glEnable( GL10.GL_CULL_FACE );
gl.glCullFace( GL10.GL_BACK );
gl.glFrontFace( GL10.GL_CCW );

gl.glLoadIdentity();

// draw the cube   
gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
gl.glEnableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
gl.glVertexPointer( 3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer );
gl.glDrawElements( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, cubeIndices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBufferCube );
gl.glDisableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

// draw the plane
gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
gl.glEnableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
gl.glVertexPointer( 3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBufferPlane );
gl.glDrawElements( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, planeIndices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBufferPlane );
gl.glDisableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
```

The problem is when I try to scale the 'plane' and do this:

```
// draw the cube   
gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
gl.glEnableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
gl.glVertexPointer( 3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer );
gl.glDrawElements( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, cubeIndices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBufferCube );
gl.glDisableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

// draw the plane
gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
gl.glScalef( 2f, 2f, 2f ); // make the plane 2x bigger
gl.glEnableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
gl.glVertexPointer( 3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBufferPlane );
gl.glDrawElements( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, planeIndices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBufferPlane );
gl.glDisableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
```

I get very weird results when navigating the scene the plane and cube moves at different speeds, not synchronized. Am I misusing the glScalef function?

All I'm trying to do is make the 'plane' model huge, cube remains the same size, and when I move around the world using GLU.gluLookAt they 'move' related to one another. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,make sure that you use `gl.glPushMatrix()` and `gl.glPopMatrix()` when you draw each object, otherwise one object's transformations may accumulate with others :

```
// draw the cube   
gl.glPushMatrix();
{
  gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
  gl.glEnableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
  gl.glVertexPointer( 3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer );
  gl.glDrawElements( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, cubeIndices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBufferCube );
  gl.glDisableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
}
gl.glPopMatrix()

// draw the plane
gl.glPushMatrix();
{
  gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
  gl.glScalef( 2f, 2f, 2f ); // make the plane 2x bigger
  gl.glEnableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
  gl.glVertexPointer( 3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBufferPlane );
  gl.glDrawElements( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, planeIndices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBufferPlane );
  gl.glDisableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
}
gl.glPopMatrix()
```

Secondly, you need to consider that when you are applying a scale, the object will be scaled around its *pivot*, the pivot position depends on how you created the mesh.

For example for your plane and your cube, the pivot needs to be at (0,0,0), which means that all the vertex positions of the cube and the plane need to be defined relative to (0,0,0) and that the pivot is at the "center" of the object.

If the pivot is not at the object's center, then when you scale in a uniform way like you do (same scale on each axis) it will get stretched more on some axises than others and you will get weird results.